# Is it a BUG of kotlin 'in' keyword?

Tags: generics, kotlin

Look at the following code. Why no warning on the line 2, and I can run it without any error?

```
fun main() {
    val testProducer: TestProducer<in Child> = TestProducer(22)
    println(testProducer.get())
}

open class Parent

class Child : Parent()

class TestProducer<T>(private val data: T) {
    fun get(): T = data
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not a bug.

`in` keyword : It makes a type parameter **contravariant**: it can only be consumed and never produced.

You might be getting confused because of the other general use of `in` keyword - that is inside for loops.

Here are all the places `in` keyword can be used :

- specifies the object being iterated in a for loop
- is used as an infix operator to check that a value belongs to a range, a collection or another entity that defines the 'contains' method
- is used in when expressions for the same purpose
- marks a type parameter as contravariant

References - [generics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html), [keyword-reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html)

Edit 1:

As mentioned in a comment,
`<in Child>` means you can pass Child objects as function parameters to it. But when it returns objects like in your `get()` function, they are treated like they are `Any?`. Your code works because `println` accepts `Any?` as a parameter.

Comment: But if I change the `in` to `out`, there will be a type mismatch error. Is it intentional？

Comment: yes, because `out` would mark type parameter as covariant

Comment: So the `TestProducer<in Child>` is equal to `TestProducer<*>` in this question. The code inspection doesn't check which generic type you specify. Right?

Comment: `<in Child>` means you can pass Child objects as function parameters to it. But when it returns objects like in your `get()` function, they are treated like they are `Any?`. Your code works because `println` accepts `Any?` as a parameter.